# 500 http error не отображается в error.log

Tags: java, android, apache

У меня есть сервер Apache, отправляю запросы с Anrdoid, получаю 500 http error на устройстве Android, на сервере ошибка появляется только в `access.log`, в `error.log` она не отображается. Что это значит? Значит ли это что на самом сервере нет ошибки? Или ошибка просто не печатается?

Пример ошибки в `access.log`:

```
77.120.254.194 - - [28/Jul/2016:17:25:47 +0300] "POST /tro/ws/kltro HTTP/1.1" 500 283
```

Comment: а ты html-страницу на этом сервере открываешь? Приведи примеры ошибки из access.log

Comment: @strangeqargo добавила пример ошибки

Answer (score 3, accepted):

если ты что-то постишь туда, значит там есть какой-то скрипт на каком-то языке, либо cgi-файл, который, наверное обрабатывает POST-запрос (иначе зачем делать POST-запрос)

если в скрипте случается ошибка, он просто выдает заголовок с ошибкой 500  и завершается, для сервера в этом случае все ок, до него ошибка не дошла, поэтому в лог ошибок ничего и не пишется. Если бы он плюнул ошибкой еще и серверу - вы бы ее заметили.

т.е. у тебя проблема не с сервером, а с кодом/скриптом/процессом, которому апач передает запрос.

вот когда ты расскажешь нам, что это за процесс/скрипт  и т.д. и заодно поставишь правильные теги, тогда мы и сможем ответить, где там ошибка.
а сейчас можно сказать только, что да, в самом сервере ошибки нет. это просто такое название, типа "ошибка на стороне сервера", но происходит она не в apache, а в коде, который обрабатывает запрос.

Comment: спасибо за пояснения!